# How can i fix Errno::ENXIO for a ruby gem installation (postgresql)

Tags: ruby, postgresql, installation, rubygems

When running a ruby installation i expected to simply load a postgresql gem.

commonly this is done using gem install postgresql, however i encounter the following error:

```
MAINPATH\Ruby\bin>gem install postgresql --debug
NOTE:  Debugging mode prints all exceptions even when rescued
Exception 'NameError' at MAINPATH/Ruby/lib/ruby/2.3.0/fiddle/import.rb:154 - uninitialized constant Fiddle::Function::STDCALL
Exception 'Errno::ENXIO' at MAINPATH/Ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/spec_fetcher.rb:62 - No such device or address @ rb_file_s_stat - Z:/
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::ENXIO)
    No such device or address @ rb_file_s_stat - Z:/
        MAINPATH/Ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/spec_fetcher.rb:62:in 'stat'
        MAINPATH/Ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/spec_fetcher.rb:62:in 'initialize'
        MAINPATH/Ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/spec_fetcher.rb:43:in 'new'
        MAINPATH/Ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/spec_fetcher.rb:43:in 'fetcher'
        MAINPATH/Ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/resolver/installer_set.rb:38:in 'initialize'
        MAINPATH/Ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/dependency_installer.rb:441:in 'new'
        MAINPATH/Ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/dependency_installer.rb:441:in 'resolve_dependencies'
        MAINPATH/Ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/commands/install_command.rb:194:in 'install_gem'
        MAINPATH/Ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/commands/install_command.rb:255:in 'block in install_gems'
        MAINPATH/Ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/commands/install_command.rb:251:in 'each'
        MAINPATH/Ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/commands/install_command.rb:251:in 'install_gems'
        MAINPATH/Ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/commands/install_command.rb:158:in 'execute'
        MAINPATH/Ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/command.rb:310:in 'invoke_with_build_args'
        MAINPATH/Ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/command_manager.rb:169:in 'process_args'
        MAINPATH/Ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/command_manager.rb:139:in 'run'
        MAINPATH/Ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:55:in 'run'
        MAINPATH/Ruby/bin/gem:21:in '<main>'
```

Normally I know how to avoid these errors but for this one I am clueless. anyone got suggestions?
Currently running PG9.5, PG10 and PG12 (different ports) and all encounter that error.

Additional information:

```
gem -v 
2.6.6

ruby -v
Ruby interpreter (CUI) 2.3.1p112 [x64-mingw32]
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a known issue of network drives

Please check this if it is relevant -

https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Troubleshooting#network_drive_home